# Java : XML Data Saving based on number of elements

Tags: java, xml, collections

Suppose i have this XML File:-

```
<logExtract>
    <query id="1">
        <otsdb_elements>
            <metricname>linecount</metricname>
            <tags>splunk_server</tags>
        </otsdb_elements>
    <splunk_query>
        <query_syn>index=_internal source=*/splunkd_access.log |head 10000</query_syn>
    </splunk_query>
</query>
<query id="2">
    <otsdb_elements>
        <metricname>line_count</metricname>
        <tags>splunk_server1</tags>
    </otsdb_elements>
    <splunk_query>
        <query_syn>index=_internal source=*/splunkd_access.log |head 100</query_syn>
    </splunk_query>
</query>
```

Suppose i parse this data from XML and i want to save data from this XML file in to variable(array, list , hashmap whatever).

Ex.

`a[0][0]=1`

`a[0][1]=linecount`

`a[0][2]=splunk_server`

`a[0][3]=index=....`

`b[0][0]=2`

`b[0][1]=line_count`

`b[0][2]=splunk_server1`

`b[0][3]=index=....`

**FYI** :- here array representation is just for example. I dont know which Java Collection to use.

What Java Collection to be used? and how ?

**FYI** :- If i parse the data and add them in HaspMap directly it will overridden by last `<query>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which collection to use depends on what you want to do with the collection. Your requirements will decide the choice. But don't limit yourself to collections. Use classes to structure data, otherwise you could end up with messes like `Map<T1, Map<T2, Map<T3, T4>>>` or `List<List<List<T>>>`.

I would recommend looking into JAXB to simplify working with XML:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/arch.html

Don't use arrays if you can avoid it!

Comment: How about `List<Map<K, V>>` ?? I mean is it Same as `Map<T1, Map<T2, Map<T3, T4>>>`?

Comment: No. One is a list of maps and the other is a map of maps.